# text exchange between two processes on a box using Memory Mapped File

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

Requirement is to be able to achieve 'chat' like communication between two console apps on the same windows box. I implemented this using named pipes, by implementing both a sender and receiver functionality in each app.

I want to try the same functionality but using Memory Mapped files (though I think it is not ideal for 'chat' type communication).

For simplicity sake, say chat messages are just strings of short length.

Here is what I have in mind:

> One app will take care of creating a mutex and the memory mapped file.
>   Call it master.
>
> In each app, we maintain two threads, one responsible for taking user
>   input and writing to the file, the other responsible for periodically
>   checking if it has something to read.
>
> So four threads in all, each governed by a mutex for access to the
>   file.
>
> Within the file, I think both should have their own 'section'. say
>   first half of the file size is for master app and the other half for
>   the second app.
>
> So when user inputs a line of text in master app, the thread accesses
>   its half of the file and tries to append new text after the last new
>   line.
>
> When app reads its section of the file for text, if there is any, app
>   reads it and blanks out its section.

Is this approach correct? Other approach would be to some how mark the message with the source id, so that the reader knows to ignore messages that are written by itself. But I feel that is unnecessary string parsing.

Also, other than each reader thread periodically trying to read their section of the file to see if there is new data, can you suggest any kind of notification mechanism? Sort of event handling? Reader thread will only go look for new messages if it gets some kind of event notification.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is not ideal by a long shot.  Messages fit a stream protocol.  Already covered very well by a named pipe, a socket and a message queue.

Comment: @HansPassant I know it is not ideal. But if you are restricted to using a single Memory Mapped File, what would be the approach?

Comment: If I'm restricted by such unsound technical choices with no say in the matter then I'd quit the job.

Comment: @HansPassant Funny..:) Incidentally, this exercise is part of a job interview, and it was mentioned MMF is an option, I am just curious, if that's the only choice, how best it can be done. I wouldn't want to quit the job even before getting hired.

Comment: Hmm, yes, fake question.  I do lots of interviews, I know the pattern.  It is a standard trick, not exactly my favorite one, propose something completely ridiculous and watch the candidate squirm to not say what he should say.  You are not being tested on your technical prowess, you are being tested for your ability to have an opinion and have enough confidence in yourself to make it stick.  It is a very important trait, nobody wants to hire a "code monkey".  The worst thing you could do is not say what you think, just because you think the interviewer knows more than you do.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Hans for the most part, memory mapped files would not nessecarily be ideal here, if you go down this road though consider using a named event (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of polling.

You may need to p/invoke to get at this functionality from c#.

On the rest give each app its own region of the file, with a control section managed by the master to coordinate who gets what.